# Hardware level encrypted flash drive not being detected in ubuntu

Tags: usb, encryption, usb-drive

I just bought an Encrypted USB storage of courier integral, more details [here](https://www.integralmemory.com/product/courier-fips-197-encrypted-usb-3-0/), I can use the stick normally on windows as highlighted, but I am not able to use this storage stick on Linux based operating systems more specifically on Ubuntu

After running the `lsb_release -a` I got the following output

> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
> Release:        18.04
> Codename:       bionic

Now according to their docs, they have not provided the support for Linux at least not mentioned in the specs and details. But I just want to confirm is there still a workaround available to use this encrypted stick in ubuntu? As I have to create some regular encrypted database backups in ubuntu server

Comment: As you mentioned … They say on their website "Compatible with Windows XP / Vista / 7 / 8.1 / 10, Mac OS X" … I don’t have access to one myself so can’t tell … Probably someone who has one of these can inform us … Strange for a hardware encryption level to be OS reliant though IMHO … Please read e.g. https://www.kingston.com/en/blog/data-security/hardware-vs-software-encryption

Comment: It sounds like the drive comes with two password checking softwares for Windows and MacOS. One of them run when you insert the USB based on which OS is detected. If this is the case, it won't work on Ubuntu unless the manufacturer writes the software for Linux.

Comment: Look for [something like this](https://www.securedrive.com/product/secureusb-kp-encrypted-flash-drive). Note the built in number keyboard. If your USB does not have that, it will depend on some software to ask for password. That software will always depend on the OS.

Comment: [This site](https://www.securedrive.com/product/secureusb-kp-encrypted-flash-drive) has some Linux friendly hardware encrypted USB examples.